# ARM and x86 in Android studio

Tags: android

What is the difference between using an ARM emulator and x86? I try to use the x86 emulator for an app but I have just get an error saying I don't have HAXM although I installed the package and my computer supports vt. So I was wondering if it makes to much difference testing the app on the ARM emulator instead of the x86.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing (what looks to be) the Intel HAXM from the SDK Manager is not enough. That just downloads the installer, you have to run it manually for the first time.

Look through [this article](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html) to get a bigger view on the topic (you can search for "HAXM" to get instructions about the installation depending on your OS).

Comment: Thank you for the link. But besides installing it I would like to know what makes different the x86 emulator from the ARM emulator

Comment: These are just system images emulating different CPUs (ARM or Intel x86). The very main difference here is that running an x86 image requires you to install the Intel accelerator (HAXM), but then things will be way faster. I'd go for x86 + HAXM.

Comment: I finally managed to install the haxm and figured out it wasn't working because the vt-x wasn't enabled in the BIOS. So I finally got the x86 emulator to work. I appreciate your help.